# Install an assembly into GAC programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, exception, gac

I need to install an assembly in GAC using c#. Below is my code:

```
new System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish().GacInstall("MyAssembly.dll");
```

The above code gives the error:

> Absolute path required

But i need this to run without using static file path (absolute path). Can anyone tell me whether its possible? I have added the reference to the assembly inside the project references. I need to install this assembly inside GAC.

Comment: Can you use `gacutil.exe` and `Process.Start()`?

Comment: I need to do it programmatically in c# project

Comment: Um. Resolve the file path to an absolute path at runtime, before attempting the install?

Comment: Right. Programmatically call `Process.Start("gacutil.exe", "/i MyAssembly.dll");`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
GacInstall((new System.IO.FileInfo("MyAssembly.dll")).FullName);
```

or,

```
GacInstall(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("MyAssembly.dll"));
```

Assuming that the file is in your current working directory. If it's not, then you need to define what rules are being used to find this DLL (e.g. is it in the same path as your current executable?)

Answer (score 2):

try this below piece I cameup with, let me know if this works

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program));//Replace your Type here.
string filePath = assembly.Location;
```

Then use this file path.

Comment: That would only work if the assembly is referenced from the program performing the GAC installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you know *relative* path of that `DLL` in regard of your executeble, make

```
string executableDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string assemblyFullPath = Path.Combine(executableDirectory,
                            relativePathToAssembly);
```

**Should** work for you.

Comment: That will not work if the process has changed the current directory after starting up, or if the process was started with a different current directory than the folder of the executing assembly. The proper way would instead be to use `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

Comment: @atornblad: you can _set_ Environment.CurrentDirectory too, by changing it's path during execution and more,  it's OS information, that will not in any way reflect your app setup.

Comment: The question does not mention anything about only wanting to register dlls that are in the same directory as the executing app.

Comment: @atornblad: and you get, paths of those assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Error itself states, that you need to give full location path of the dll residing. ie C:\myprojects\myassembly.dll in the path

Answer (score -3):

Simple steps to add a ".dll" file into the Global Assembly Cache in c#:

1. In your project, "Add reference" to the .dll file you want to install in the GAC
2. Form the References, right click on the particular .dll file and select "Properties"
3. Change the property "Copy Local" to "True"
4. Build and deploy using wspBuilder
5. For verification, just check in the manifest file whether the path exists or not and also in "C:\Windows\assembly".

Comment: Reviving this, sorry about that. But this isn't exactly a programmatic way of doing it.