# gacutil is not recognized as an internal or external command?

Tags: c#, console

I   have  created  a Console Application With Adding External Dll Ref.
  Now  i  have to deploy my External Dll to my Assembly.
  When i was trying to add my dll in GAC.

```
  GACUTIL.EXE /i MyLibrary.dll
```

command to add my  dll into Assembly , Its showing me error

```
*gacutil is not recognized as an internal or external comma*
```

how  can  i  fix?

Comment: Provide a full path to gacutil.exe?

Comment: Type for ex `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe"`

Comment: I  have  tried with Visul studio Command Prompt is working  fine  .But how can i deploy my dll on Client Server because he might don't have visual studio

Comment: any  how  if  you  have  answer  then  please  tell

Comment: @KapsHasija you could look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12382831/238902).

Comment: Gacutil.exe is a Windows SDK tool, it won't be available on the target machine.  Create a Setup project instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"But how can i deploy my dll on Client Server because he might don't have visual studio"

If I remember correctly, gacutil is also present in C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\some folder\

Another way: If using a primitive .cmd => You could bundle gacutil.exe and gacutil.exe.config along with your script.

Yet another way: If you are using windows installer, that has in built support for GACing assemblies.

Also, note that there are different GACs for x86 and x64 assemblies (ignore if your assembly is MSIL).

Comment: in my client  server "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin"  is  empty  no  gac  file there

Answer (score 17):

For **Windows 10** path is:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin`

Comment: There is no 'Microsoft SDKs' folder at that location.

Answer (score 12):

If you already installed Visual studio then you can use [Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) instead of normal `Command prompt` to access the `gacutil` directly.

You can find `Developer Command Prompt` here:

`Start Menu > Visual Studio 20XX > Developer Command Prompt for VS20XX`

Comment: Note: I need to use GacUtil becuase the IDE won't load...so this is Runnable IDE solution BUT not for Failure to Launch IDEs ;)

Answer (score 4):

Our Production Box running Windows Server 2016 does not have MS SDK tools for Global-Assembly cache (GAC)!!!  So I copied the whole directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\
```

from my Development laptop (Windows 10 that has VS 2017 installed) to that production server where I want to have my .dll's registered to my production server's Global Assembly.
[image: copy GACUtil.exe from a dir to the other computer]

The assemblies I need to register are : _Net35scannersMonitor.dll which is x86 dotNet 2.0 and _Net40scannersMonitor.dll which is x64 dotNet 4.x.

At the prompt of directory where my copied gacUtil is, I entered:

```
  gacutil -i D:\resource\Library\_Net35scannersMonitor.dll
```

and

```
  gacutil -i D:\resource\Library\_Net40scannersMonitor.dll
```

I used the same gacUtil.exe (file version 4.6.1055.0) to do both.  And they both end up at the right place dotnet2x86(C:\Windows\assembly) and dotnet4(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL) -- 
I don't have to use 2 different gacUtil.exe's.

Result:

[image: The x86 .dll and x64 .dll went to correct assembly respectively]

Conclusion: Even your box has no VS installed, you can copy your gacutil.exe with its bin from the PC which has VS installed.  No special download/install needed.  Then you can use the copied gacutil for both x86 and x64 assemblies!!!

Answer (score 3):

probable duplicate : [GAC 32bit vs. 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507675/gac-32bit-vs-64bit)
(gacutil is no more part of client OS since .Net 3.0 at least, you need to use a proper installer or to install the windows SDK which is clearly overkill)

Comment: is there honestly no easy way to get a tool which shows what's in GAC?