# Cannot add reference on Visual Studio 2017 project

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and trying to add a new reference between two projects, however I get following error when I click on "Add Reference..."

> Cannot find an instance of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsReferenceManager service.

The first project is `Asp.Net Core`, and the second project is a `.NET Core` Class Library.

Comment: Does re-installing Visual Studio help?

Comment: Have you opened **each** project using VS2017 before trying to add the reference?

Comment: No.
I only opened both projects with some solution file.

Answer (score 14):

I had this issue with all my projects after installing another version of Visual Studio.

I fixed it by following 宝宝徐's advice [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/officeocs/en-US/4eea5785-0a83-4389-89e3-209a5a4432c0/referencemanagerpackage-fails-to-install-vs-2017-community-edition?forum=vssetup), namely running the following commands in command prompt:

```
CD C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies
gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll
```

I found out that on my machine (Windows 10 x64), apparently gacutil is no longer bundled with new versions of Windows, so retrieved it from a previously installed Microsoft Windows SDK which I found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin, although I think you may need to install it first. There are some thoughts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386352/gacutil-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) about finding gacutil on Windows 10.

After this, I was able to add references to projects again.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: This worked for me. I just copied the gacutil files over to the visual studio folder specified above(but in my case was for 2019) and then it worked. Thanks!

Comment: once command executed successfully, please restart visual studio

Answer (score 4):

You can go into the csproj of the project you wish to add the reference to and add the following xml

```
<ItemGroup>
 <ProjectReference Include="..\path\to\your\other.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

That will add the reference to the other project.

Comment: And it is also possible to walk to work in the event your car doesn't start. This isn't a solution, just a workaround that will quickly get tiresome.

Comment: You are right, it is a work around. Although it doesn't negate the fact that it does work for this case. Also, its how I've always managed my project references. I think GUI's are more tiresome than appending a line to a file. To each there own....

Answer (score 1):

=>Run the "developer Command Prompt as administrator"

=>Goto the path "CD C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\**20XX**\**Enterprise**\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies"

**N.B :** **20XX**=2017,2019 etc and **Enterprise**=Enterprise,Community etc

=>Run gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll

=>Restart your pc

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error after migrating Visual Studio 2017 project to Visual Studio 2019. In my case I used Visual Studio Installer and under features there was Visual Studio SDK which was unchecked. After installing that, problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was just easier to go to NuGet and Browse for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0 then add.